# Truffle Migrate Rinkeby - Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block: Error: ETIMEDOUT

Tags: truffle-migration, infura, rinkeby

I am facing this error when on running truffle migrate on Rinkeby network with my infura

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the fix by changing the infura Rinkeby RPC_URL in 'the truffle-config.js' file.

Originally I was using the https://rinkeby_url.
On using wss://rinkeby_url - it got fixed.
Please see a snapshot of the URL from infura. You can create a account on infura and generate these URL.
[image: Example of URL from Infura]

Example of my truffle-config.js

```
    rinkeby: {
      provider: () => {
        return new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, process.env.RINKEBY_RPC_URL)
      },
      network_id: "4",
      networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      addressIndex: 2

    },
```

Comment: Please fix the typo and provide the url you actually used, not the env var where you stored it...

Comment: need url not the env variable

Comment: @DeepakBhavsar
I have fixed one typo. And sorry I cannot display the complete URL, although I have added a cut snapshot for the same. You can easily generate your RPC URL from Infura.

Comment: That just saved my life.. Thank you so much. @sahilkharya
How did you find this solution?

Comment: @AlonBA - You are welcome. I was facing the issue and just tried different approaches, changing values and was able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. Here is how I resolved this problem:

I saw this error message, just saying "this operation is timeout", don't just focus on this error, you should also check the browser with the transaction id.

e.g.

Step1. I ran this command to deploy:

```
truffle deploy --network goerli --verbose-rpc --interactive --skip-dry-run --reset
```

and it may give this error :

```
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
undefined
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (/mnt/d/workspace/test_truffle/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51:24)
```

so, let increase the timeout config:

```
// truffle-config.js 
require('dotenv').config();
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const { INFURA_API_URL, MNEMONIC } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
    goerli: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, INFURA_API_URL),
      network_id: '5',
      gas: 5500000,

      // you can also increase the gas price from default to 50 gwei, which is very high in 2022.6
      gasPrice: 50000000000,

      //  This is the timeout config. set it to 1000 seconds
      networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,    
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      addressIndex: 2
    }
  }
};
```

step2. run the command again, and you would get an output looks like:

[image]

copy this tx and view it on goerli.etherscan.io:  you may found it's pending

[image]

step3. let's increase the gas price from default to 50Gwei, then resend this rpc call:

```
// truffle-config.js

    goerli: {
      // ....
      // you can also increase the gas price from default to 50 gwei, which is very high in 2022.6
      gasPrice: 50000000000,

    }
```

then re-execute the command:

```
truffle deploy --network goerli --verbose-rpc --interactive --skip-dry-run --reset
```

then everything looks fine:

[image]

step4. finally , I checked the blockchain browser when I met "752 seconds timeout", I found at that time, all people's tx is pending ( another word, there's no one successful block minted during 40 minutes) . see the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use compile-none when deploying. If your migration file has a lot of contracts to compile, truffle sends requests to get latest block. If provider limits the number of calls you can do it, it will timeout. Use compile-none and it will work fine.

More details here: [BSC Testnet: Truffle Migrate ETIMEDOUT](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98322/bsc-testnet-truffle-migrate-etimedout)

Answer (score 0):

In my project, it seems that removing other attributes than these three: providers, network_id, and gas somehow solves the problem.

`rinkeby: { provider: () => new HDWalletProvider( numonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/{id}" ), network_id: 4, // chain_id: 5, gas: 5500000, }`